Riemann sum - convergence rate for Kernel function
Let $K$ be a Lipschitz-continuous function on $[-1, 1]$ with $K(x) = 0$ for $|x| > 1$. Consider a sequence $\{b_n\}$ with $b_n > 0$ satisfying $b_n \to 0$ and $n b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.
How can I show that the following approximation holds uniformly for any $u \in [0,1]$:
$$
        \vert \frac{1}{n b_n} \sum_{t=1}^n K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) - \int_{\frac{u-1}{b_n}}^{u / b_n} K(x) dx \vert  = O(\frac{1}{n b_n})$$
Currently, I can achieve a rate of $O\left(\frac{1}{n b_n^2}\right)$, which does not match the desired bound. Any suggestions on how to improve this rate to the optimal $O\left(\frac{1}{n b_n}\right)$ would be greatly appreciated.
We could consider the following computation.
$$  \vert \frac{1}{n b_n} \sum_{t=1}^n K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) - \int_{\frac{u-1}{b_n}}^{u / b_n} K(x) dx \vert  = \vert \frac{1}{n b_n} \sum_{t=1}^n K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) - \sum_{t=1}^{n} \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} K(x) dx \vert \\ 
 = \vert  \sum_{t=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n b_n} K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) - \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} K(x) dx \vert \\ 
= \vert  \sum_{t=1}^{n}  \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) - \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} K(x) dx \vert \\ 
\leq \sum_{t=1}^{n} \vert  \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) -  K(x) dx \vert 
\\ 
\leq \sum_{t=1}^{n}  \int_{\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u - (t-1)/n}{b_n}} \vert  K\left(\frac{u-t / n}{b_n}\right) -  K(x) \vert   dx
\\ 
=  \sum_{t=1}^{n}  \int_0^{n b_n}\left|K\left(\frac{u-i / n}{b_n}\right)-K\left(\frac{u-i / n}{b_n}+x\right)\right| dx  \\ 
\leq \sum_{t = 1}^n M \int_0^{n b_n} x dx = O(\frac{1}{n b_n^2})$$

This is a generalised versionof riemmann summing, also consider that a lot of these summing terms are zero

First let us begin with a small computation. Let $1\leq i \leq n $
$$\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{nb_n} K\left(\frac{u - i/n}{b_n} \right) - \int_{\frac{u-i/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u-(i-1)/n}{b_n}} K(x) \operatorname{d}\!x \right|
&= \left|\int_{\frac{u-i/n}{b_n}}^{\frac{u-(i-1)/n}{b_n}} K\left(\frac{u - i/n}{b_n}\right) - K(x) \operatorname{d}\!x \right|\\
&\leqslant \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{nb_n}} \left|  K\left(\frac{u - i/n}{b_n}\right) - K\left(\frac{u-i/n}{b_n} +x \right)\right| \operatorname{d}\!x \\
&\leqslant \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{nb_n}} Mx \operatorname{d}\!x \\
&= \frac{M}{2n^2b_n^2}\end{align*}$$
Where $M$ is the lipschitz constant of $K$.
Now one would think that we are stuck since multiplying by $n$ just gives us $\frac{M}{2nb_n^2}$ which is not good since we don’t know the behavior of this sequence, but in reality, how many non-zero terms do we have in this very sum?
Remember that for $|x|>1$, $K(x) =0$, so let us check  for which value of $t \in [0,n]$ we have $K\left(\frac{u-t/n}{b_n} \right) = 0$. It is simply for $\left|\frac{u-t/n}{b_n}  \right| > 1$, i.e.
$$|nu-t| > nb_n$$

Case one $u-t/n \geq 0$, i.e. $t \leq nu$, then we have necessarily $t < n(u-b_n)$
Case two, $u-t/, \leq 0$, i.e. $t \geq nu$, then we have necessarily $t > n(b_n+u)$
For the first one this gives us the interval $[0, nu-nb_n[$ and for the second one the interval $]nu +nb_n, n]$ So the interval where it is non-zero is $[nu-nb_n,nu+nb_n]$ of width $2nb_n$.

In summary, we just have to sum at most $2nb_n$ terms here so
$$\left| \frac{1}{nb_n} \sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{u - i/n}{b_n} \right) - \int_{\frac{u-1}{b_n}}^{\frac{u}{b_n}} K(x) \operatorname{d}\!x \right|
\leq 2nb_n \cdot \frac{M}{2n^2b_n^2} = \frac{M}{nb_n} = O\left( \frac{1}{nb_n}\right).$$
Disclaimer, maybe the inequality has one or two more non zero terms not taken into account, but in the end it would be a result in $O \left(\frac{1}{n^2b^2_n} \right)$ so it would not matter.

Thank you for the excellent answer! I attempted to rewrite the full computation in my question, but I’m still unsure how to incorporate the requirement that $t$ should only be considered within the interval $ t \in [n u - n b_n, n u + n b_n]$ from a mathematical perspective. Could you clarify how to formally integrate this constraint?

@Eryna I would just cut the sum into three parts: $0 < t <nu - nb_n$, then $nu-nb_n \leq t \leq nu+nb_n$ and lastly $nu+nb_n < t \leq n$. Only the middle one is non zero (but you have to be extra careful for the term in the integral that may not be non zero, so you could extend it to $[nu-n_bn-1,nu+nb_n + 1]$ just to be sure that the part in the intergal is also zero. It gives you $2nb_n +2$ terms at most so it is still okay
